# Java: concerning nested classes

Tags: java, class

I have a few classes I need: Score, Course, and handicap. The file is "handicap.java", thus the main class is "handicap".

If I try and nest the Score class or the Course class inside of the "handicap" class, I receive this error upon trying to instantiate an instance of either class:

```
handicap.java:129: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
                        Score sc = new Score(score, course);
                                   ^
handicap.java:141: put(java.util.GregorianCalendar,Score) in java.util.Map<java.util.GregorianCalendar,Score> cannot be applied to (java.util.GregorianCalendar,handicap.Score)
                        g.scores.put(greg, sc);
```

If I add "static" to the Score class declaration, I still receive the second error. Help?

The Code is here: http://pastebin.com/CvT1SCvb

Comment: You need to show the code, not just the error messages.

Comment: the code is not complete ..lots of missing stuff .. structure it so that its easier to debug

Answer (score 1):

take a look on this

```
public class Handicap {

    public class Score{

    }

    public static class ScoreStatic{

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Handicap h = new Handicap();
        h.method();
        new Handicap.ScoreStatic();
    }

    public void method(){
        new Handicap.Score();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it , you are getting compilation error.

Please read about the Nested Classes :      `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html`

This is the way it works :

```
    public class handicap{
    public static void main(String... args) {
         handicap st = new handicap();
         handicap.Score fl = st.new Score();

     }

    class Score{
      //blah
     }

   }
```